# struts 1.2 with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, struts, struts-1

how to make synchronous Ajax call using dojo.event.connect. Basically for asynchronous Ajax call, if two call is there means it will load parallel. So i want make a call synchronous if the call is executed fully then after only second call should invoke. please help me

Comment: If you want it synchronous, why don't you use simple HTTP request/response sequencing, via HTTP GET or HTTP POST?

Comment: okay i agree.. i am using two Ajax call for populating the values, one for get the id and another for populate the values based on coming id from first Ajax call..but the problem is these two calls are loading parallel. So before getting id second Ajax call also executed. So i need to do, once the 1st call is finished and got the id, after that only have to call that 2nd Ajax call with this id from 1st Ajax call... Please help me.. Advance thanks

Comment: no one is there to answer for my question?